# Extract a specific time in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to extract the dates after 30-09-2019. I used the function where but it doesn't work.

Part of my code:

```
select
    TRUNC(order_date),
    warranty_period,
    to_char(order_date + warranty_period,'DD-MM-YYYY')
from oe.order_items 
where to_char(o.order_date + f.warranty_period,'DD-MM-YYYY') >= '30-09-2019';
```

order_date - date, warranty_period - interval year to month

Comment: What's your input data and expexcted result?

Answer (score 1):

When working with dates, then do exactly that - work with dates; don't compare strings.

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (order_date date,
  2  warranty_period interval year to month);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (date '2015-03-28', interval '5-6' year to month);

1 row created.
```

Query:

```
SQL> select trunc(order_date),
  2    warranty_period,
  3    order_date + warranty_period
  4  from test
  5  where order_date + warranty_period >= date '2019-09-30';

TRUNC(ORDE WARRANTY_P ORDER_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
2015-03-28 +05-06     2020-09-28

SQL>
```